# Getting data from a MPI message before it is recieve

Tags: mpi

I was wondering if there is a way to get bits of data in an MPI message before it is actually received. I know there is probe that gives you size and status information etc., but I'm trying to get part of the actual contents of the message before it is copied into memory, if that is possible.

Comment: Where do you expect to read the message from, if not memory?

Answer (score 2):

No. In order to receive the message payload, you have to provide a buffer to receive it. The reason for this that the implementation doesn't have to provide its own buffers this way. If the implementation has to provide buffers, that adds lots of new overhead (buffer allocation/deallocation, more memory copies, etc.).

The longer version would require more information from you. What are you trying to do? How would expect such a thing to work? In what situation would this be useful?